# Stacked barplot in pandas- read from dataframe?

Tags: pandas, stacked-chart

I am trying to create a stacked barplot using a data frame I have created that 
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOx4y.png)

I want the stacked bar chart to show the 'types of exploitation' on the x axis, and then the male and female figures stacked on top of each other under these headings.

Is there a way to do this reading the info from my df? I have read about creating an index to do this but do not understand if this is the solution?

I also need a legend showing 'male' and 'female'

Answer (score 0):

You can stack bars on top of eachother by the bottom function in matplotlib package.

Step 1: Create dataframe and import packages

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
d = {'male': [37,1032,1], 'female': [96,134,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Step 2: Create graph

```
r = [0,1,2]
bars1 = df['female']
bars2 = df['male']
plt.bar(r, bars1)
plt.bar(r, bars2,bottom=bars1, color='#557f2d')
plt.xticks(r, df.index, fontweight='bold')
plt.legend(labels = ['female', 'male'])
plt.show()
```

More information could be found on this webpage: [Link](https://python-graph-gallery.com/12-stacked-barplot-with-matplotlib/)